# Python Google Spreadsheet API Bubble Chart not properly displayed

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, bubble-chart

I use the Google example https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart to test the Google Spreadshhet API v4 with Python v3.7.8 to create a bubble chart.

The data are stored in a Spreadsheet in a Google Drive where I create the bubble chart.

[image]

The bubble chart is created but the bubbles are not visible/displayed. Hereafter the code:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

...

body = {'requests': 
        [{'addChart': 
          {'chart': 
           {'spec': 
            {'title': 'Correlation between life expectancy, fertility rate and population of some world countries (2010)', 
             'titleTextPosition': 
             {'horizontalAlignment': 'CENTER'}, 
             'bubbleChart': 
             {'legendPosition': 'RIGHT_LEGEND',
              'domain': 
              {'sourceRange': 
               {'sources': 
                [{'sheetId': 909072886, 
                  'startRowIndex': 17, 
                  'endRowIndex': 27, 
                  'startColumnIndex': 1, 
                  'endColumnIndex': 2}]}}, 
              'series': 
              {'sourceRange': 
               {'sources': 
                [{'sheetId': 909072886, 
                  'startRowIndex': 17, 
                  'endRowIndex': 27, 
                  'startColumnIndex': 2, 
                  'endColumnIndex': 3}]}}, 
              'groupIds': 
              {'sourceRange': 
               {'sources': 
                [{'sheetId': 909072886, 
                 'startRowIndex': 17, 
                 'endRowIndex': 27, 
                 'startColumnIndex': 3, 
                 'endColumnIndex': 4}]}}, 
              'bubbleLabels': 
              {'sourceRange': 
               {'sources': 
                [{'sheetId': 909072886, 
                  'startRowIndex': 17, 
                  'endRowIndex': 27, 
                  'startColumnIndex': 0, 
                  'endColumnIndex': 1}]}}, 
              'bubbleSizes': 
              {'sourceRange': 
               {'sources': 
                [{'sheetId': 909072886, 
                  'startRowIndex': 17, 
                  'endRowIndex': 27, 
                  'startColumnIndex': 4, 
                  'endColumnIndex': 5}]}}, 
              'bubbleOpacity': 1.0}}, 
            'position': 
            {'overlayPosition': 
             {'anchorCell': 
              {'sheetId': 909072886, 
               'rowIndex': 61, 
               'columnIndex': 6}, 
               'offsetXPixels': 0, 
               'offsetYPixels': 0, 
               'widthPixels': 600, 
               'heightPixels': 371
             }
            }
           }
          }
         }
        ]
       }

response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=file_id, body=body).execute()
```

I should get the following:

[image]

But I get this:

> no bubbles displayed. Remark: with mouse over the (non visible) bubble, it displays all the right data (life expectancy, fertility rate, poupulation, region with the right color) of the country!

[image]

Don't hesitate to support me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would like to propose to include `bubbleMaxRadiusSize` and `bubbleMinRadiusSize` in the request body as follows. When your request body is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
'bubbleOpacity': 1.0}},
```

#### To:

```
'bubbleOpacity': 1.0,
'bubbleMaxRadiusSize': 50,
'bubbleMinRadiusSize': 5
}},
```

- In this modification, `50` and `5` are used as the sample values for `bubbleMaxRadiusSize` and `bubbleMinRadiusSize`, respectively. So please modify these values for your actual situation.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Whole script:

```js
body = {'requests': [{'addChart': {'chart': {'spec': {'title': 'Correlation between life expectancy, fertility rate and population of some world countries (2010)', 'titleTextPosition': {'horizontalAlignment': 'CENTER'},
     'bubbleChart': {
    'legendPosition': 'RIGHT_LEGEND',
    'domain': {'sourceRange': {'sources': [{
        'sheetId': 909072886,
        'startRowIndex': 17,
        'endRowIndex': 27,
        'startColumnIndex': 1,
        'endColumnIndex': 2,
        }]}},
    'series': {'sourceRange': {'sources': [{
        'sheetId': 909072886,
        'startRowIndex': 17,
        'endRowIndex': 27,
        'startColumnIndex': 2,
        'endColumnIndex': 3,
        }]}},
    'groupIds': {'sourceRange': {'sources': [{
        'sheetId': 909072886,
        'startRowIndex': 17,
        'endRowIndex': 27,
        'startColumnIndex': 3,
        'endColumnIndex': 4,
        }]}},
    'bubbleLabels': {'sourceRange': {'sources': [{
        'sheetId': 909072886,
        'startRowIndex': 17,
        'endRowIndex': 27,
        'startColumnIndex': 0,
        'endColumnIndex': 1,
        }]}},
    'bubbleSizes': {'sourceRange': {'sources': [{
        'sheetId': 909072886,
        'startRowIndex': 17,
        'endRowIndex': 27,
        'startColumnIndex': 4,
        'endColumnIndex': 5,
        }]}},
    'bubbleOpacity': 1.0,
    'bubbleMaxRadiusSize': 50,  # Added
    'bubbleMinRadiusSize': 5,  # Added
    }}, 'position': {'overlayPosition': {
    'anchorCell': {'sheetId': 909072886, 'rowIndex': 61, 'columnIndex': 6},
    'offsetXPixels': 0,
    'offsetYPixels': 0,
    'widthPixels': 600,
    'heightPixels': 371,
    }}}}}]}

response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=file_id, body=body).execute()
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [BubbleChartSpec](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#BubbleChartSpec)

Comment: Great it works! I am surprised I thought there were default values for these 2 fields.

Comment: @hganger Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.